# Extracting text element from complex xml document with pandas

Tags: python, xml, pandas

I am quite new to python and pandas and I am trying to extract a text element out of an xml that is structured like below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1wFP.png)

What I am trying to do is extract the text that is in

under block class = "full_text" and save it in a separate file. I have tried some methods but none has worked so far. Can someone help me out here? The complex structure is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_output = open('my_new_file.txt', 'w')
flag = False
with open('my_xml_file.xml') as f:
    for line in f:
        if flag and '</block>' in line:
            flag = False
        if flag:
            file_output.write(line.rstrip('</p>').lstrip('<p>') + '\n')
        if 'class="full_text"' in line:
            flag = True
file_output.close()
```